# How to insert string into linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, insertion-sort

I want to write a function which can be insert string alphabetically.
It can be declared as;

```
typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct Node
{
    char *data;
    Node *next;
};

Node *insertion(Node *head,char *arr);
```

How can I define this function?

My codes;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct Node
{
    char *data;
    Node *next;
};
Node *MyList = 0;
void AddWord(char *word) // Add a new word to the list MyList
    { Node *item,*next;
    item = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if ( item==0 ) { printf ("Malloc Failed \n");  return ; }
    strcpy(item->data,word); // Copy Word into new Item
    item->next = 0; // Set that next Item is nothing

    if ( MyList == 0 ) // If List is Empty, make this the first item
        { MyList = item; return ; }

    if(strcmp(word,MyList->data) < 0 ) // Check if the new item comes before the first item in old list
        { item->next = MyList; MyList = item; return ; }

    // Check to see if an item is inserted before the next item
    for ( next = MyList ; next ->next != 0 ; next = next ->next )
        {
        if (strcmp (word, next->next->data) < 0 )
            { // Insert Item before the next Item.
            item ->next = next->next;
            next->next = item ; return;
            }
        }

    // There are no more items ! Add to end
    next ->next = item;
    }
```

Comment: While sorting on input to create an ordered list is fine, just be aware there is no way to get the original order back. If you are reading a text file for example, sorting on insert makes for an interesting read. To preserve flexibility in your list, consider inserting in native order, the writing a sort function for the list. Above `item->data` is not allocated. Additionally, do not cast the return of `malloc`. `item = malloc (sizeof *item)` is fine, then `item->data = malloc ( strlen (word) + 1)` (the `* sizeof (char)` is implied)

Answer (score 0):

```
item = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
if ( item==0 ) { printf ("Malloc Failed \n");  return ; }
strcpy(item->data,word); // Copy Word into new Item
```

item->data is a non-initialized pointer. You should either allocate space to copy into, or declare you data as an array in the Node structure:

char data[someSize];